# Calculus problem properties of roots of polynomials

Tags: calculus

If two real polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ of degrees $m (\ge 2)$ and $n (≥ 1)$ respectively, satisfy $f(x^2+ 1) = f(x)g(x)$,

for every $x ∈ R$ , then

(A) $f$ has exactly one real root $x_0$ such that $f '(x_0) \ne 0$

(B) $f$ has exactly one real root $x_0$ such that $f '(x_0) = 0$

(C) $f$ has $m$ distinct real roots

(D) $f$ has no real root.

How to solve this? I don't know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(D) is true and all others are false: If $f(x_0)=0\,$ then $f(x_0^2+1)=0\,$ and because $x^2+1=x\,$ has no real solution this would imply that $f$ has more than $m$ roots.

Comment: Rather this would mean that $f$ has infinitely many real roots.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay A polynomial of degree $m$ has exactly $m$ roots (real or complex), so certainly not infinitely many, thus it's not possible that $f$ has *any* real root.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay: Yes of course, but more than $m$ suffice to show the contradiction.

Comment: Yes, yes, I know. I was just pointing out this fact and that it was creating a contradiction to the Gauss' theorem.